# Yml file located in folder of ADO repo does not start unit test

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I have a YAML file located in an Azure DevOps repository. This YAML file was migrated from GUI pipelines in ADO.

The idea is that this YAML file should start after we create a pull request to the branch, in order to conduct unit tests. The name of this YAML file is added to the "Build validation" in the branch that we want to test.

The file is located in the folder `devops\pipeline`.

Error that I have: *Build not run*

The most interesting thing is that if you mention the pipeline itself, which has a GUI setting, it works correctly.

started first code in yaml file

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest
variables:
  NetVersion: '6'
  BuildConfiguration: Release

steps:

- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET $(NetVersion).x sdk '
  inputs:
    version: $(NetVersion).x
    includePreviewVersions: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error that I have: Build not run

I can reproduce the same if the yaml build doesn't exist:

[image]

Please make sure the build pipeline exists before you create Pull request.

In addition, please also make sure the `trigger` setting is `automatic` on the build validation.
[image]

The pipeline in Pull request works now:

[image]

Comment: > Please manually run the pipeline at least once before you create Pull request.
Could you please enplane a little bit more? For example I have a file in devops/pipelines/pr-unit-test-approvement.yml should I create a new pipeline using this yml file?

Comment: You should have the pipeline which uses the yml file, even it's never run before(update on reply). This is because when you set up the [build validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#build-validation), it requires the pipeline not  yaml file. Please note it's used for DevOPs git repo, if it's github/bitbucket repo, you should use [pr trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers) in yaml.

Comment: After you create the pipeline, please delete the existing build validation setting on branch policy, and add it again to choose the build, and choose `Automatic` trigger. Recreate the pull request for a check.

Comment: zhou Thank you, I think I have it figured out. I created a new pipeline using the yml file, ran it, then added the name of that pipeline to "Build Validation" and the build was successful